# Perform critical un-deferrable work in a system application service

Tags: android

I am working with a system application. It has to perform some extremely critical tasks in a service that are triggered by broadcasts from the system.

Due to the [background execution limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) introduced in Oreo, I've been thinking a lot about how to perform the tasks in the background.

The tasks have the following requirements:

- They may not be deferred, they have to be started instantly.
- They shall be started even if the phone is idle (or dozing, I haven't really understood the difference)
- They are highly critical. They shall complete after being started, under all circumstances.

I looked into using IntentService. But, they recommend using JobIntentService instead due to the background execution restrictions. However, this doesn't comply with my requirement of not deferring the work. It also says that JobScheduler does not run during doze. When running on O or later, JobIntentService will perform the task as a JobService Job:

> When running as a Job, it will be subject to standard JobScheduler policies for a Job with a setOverrideDeadline(long) of 0: the job will not run while the device is dozing, it may get delayed more than a service if the device is under strong memory pressure with lots of demand to run jobs.

It seems like using a regular IntentService may expose the tasks to the possibility to be stopped/killed by the system under certain circumstances, imposed by the new restrictions from Oreo and above.

The safest option seems to be to launch a foreground service. But, I don't necessarily want to show a notification during the service's lifetime. Also, I believe that if the user accidentally disables the notification channel in the settings, the service cannot be started anymore. I'm also worried about edge  cases where the system may arbitrarily kill or stop my service, or simply stop my work in some other way by not honoring my wake lock etc.

I recently came across the `android:persistent` in the application tag in the manifest. It says it can only be used by system applications. According to [this blog post from 2011](http://devescape.blogspot.com/2011/02/persistent-services-in-android.html) setting this attribute to true renders your application and it's services un-killable. It also implies that it can let you have a background service that is "always alive". But how does this relate to doze, battery optimizations etc? Do I still have to acquire a wake lock and [whitelist my app from battery optimizations](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) in order to continue performing the background work during doze conditions?

Thanks a lot for reading and I hope you have some valuable input. I am currently a bit confused, trying to put all the pieces together. It doesn't help that the documentation is (as per usual)... lacking.

Comment: *It also implies that it can let you have a background service that is "always alive". But how does this relate to doze, battery optimizations etc?* doze & friends did not exist in 2011. Hell, in 2011 there were no restrictions to background work at all. You have few requirements but they are very demanding and as far as I know, they are not compatible with android. At least not when combined.

Comment: It's frustrating that they're pushing more and more for WorkManager, selling it as the one and only solution for background work. But what if the work is not deferrable? Then bad luck, back to using some hacky workaround solution. I'm currently launching a foreground service with a partial wake lock, just hoping I'm not going to run into any problems in the future.

Comment: Foreground service is the most reliable, as in least likely to get killed, but it comes with other downsides you surely already know of. Using hacky workarounds is not really an option these days. At least I'm not aware of any such workarounds

Comment: The questions still stands though, if android:persistent="true" might have an impact on how the app's services are treated in regards to doze etc.